# Cannot Convert Listview to Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I am trying to convert layout to bitmap. The layout contains Textview and Listview. Textview is displaying in Bitmap but Listview is displaying but not displaying(showing empty) in drawing cache. Here is my code

Print.xml

```
   <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/screen_print1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical">

              <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tax_amnt"
               android:layout_width="360dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:text="Tax  : $200" />    

             <ListView
               android:id="@+id/item_listview1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="200dp"
               android:layout_gravity="center" />                  
     </LinearLayout>
```

Print.java

```
 LinearLayout screenshot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.screen_print1);
    ListView items_display=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.item_listview1);
    TextView tax_amount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tax_amnt);
    tax_amount.setText("$5000");

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bill_list1=OrderSummaryFragment.item_lists;
    itl1 = new Itemlist(getApplicationContext(), bill_list1);
    items_display.setAdapter(itl1);

    screenshot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    screenshot.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = screenshot.getDrawingCache();
    screen_imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Call `itl1.notifyDataSetChanged()` right after your setAdapter() call, or are the items displaying properly but not appearing in the drawing cache?

Comment: yes items are displaying but not appearing in drawing cache..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update the lines**

```
screenshot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
screenshot.buildDrawingCache();
```

**to**

```
screenshot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);    
screenshot.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
screenshot.layout(0, 0, screenshot.getMeasuredWidth(), screenshot.getMeasuredHeight());
screenshot.buildDrawingCache(true);
```